# How do I install Groovy in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, java

I don't know how to install files to Ubuntu. Kindly explain to me how to install Groovy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fast way is to install from the command line. Type the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

You can also use Software Center from Ubuntu->Software Center to install Groovy.
Type Groovy in the search box and after selecting the first option, click Install button.

[image]

Comment: `apt install groovy` leads to a broken installation on Ubuntu 22.04: ```╰─$ groovy --version
groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
```

Answer (score 5):

To install through command-line, make sure that your package list is updated and then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install groovy
```

Reference:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/universe/groovy/