# How to install Groovy in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to install Groovy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30022/how-to-install-groovy)

I need to install Groovy 1.8.2 in my Ubuntu 10.04. Here is the site download [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download). There are two options available: binary download and source download. I don't know which one to do for Ubuntu since I'm from a Windows background where I will just run the .exe file and the job is done.

And note that from command prompt I have tried to install it, it shows only the previous version of Groovy 1.7. But I need to install Groovy 1.8. Since I'm a novice in Ubuntu, it will be good if the answer is in simple steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say downloading the [Debian installer](http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions/installers/deb/groovy_1.8.2-1_all.deb), then clicking on the file and providing your password to confirm your permission to install software would do the trick.

`.deb` files roughly equivalent to `.msi` files in Windows :) They often also include pre- and post-install scripts to configure the system, so I would expect everything to be in a useable state once you install it.

Example: installing Apache configures it with some basic defaults and even starts the server so you can access http://localhost/ and see "It works!" page straight away.

Comment: have a doubt.. I have already installed Groovy 1.7 in my system. Before running the Debian package is it necessary to remove 1.7 version and then run? Or the Debian installer will replace 1.7 with 1.8?

Comment: It may be able to upgrade but, provided the packages come from different sources, it definitely would be safer to remove (or even purge - i.e. including the configuration files) the old version before installing the new one.